# jQuery Autocomplete source property as function(){} is very slow

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have two test cases using a reasonably large json object (1.2mb):

```
source: data
```

and

```
source: function (request, response) {
                response(data);
            }
```

In the first case the autocomplete works as I'd expect.

In the second case, autocomplete works occasionally and is very slow. Sometimes the browser hangs for 3-4 seconds "not responding" before it frees up again.

What's happening differently in the second case compared to the first?

(I wil be putting some filtering logic in this function at some point but for now I'm testing like this).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your data set is being filtered when passing it in as a local object, but is not being filtered when using the callback (would be the programmers responsibility).

When using `source: data` autocomplete filters the result set for you:

```
response($.ui.autocomplete.filter(array, request.term));
```

When using the callback `source: function(request, response) { response(data) }` no filtering is being applied, thus your page is generating markup for 1.3MB of json.

<strike>When autocomplete loads data from a local source it caches the data. When it is retrieved remotely it is not cached by default.</strike>

This jQuery UI Autocomplete documentation explains the behavior and suggests how to implement caching for a remote call.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote-with-cache

Comment: Are you suggesting that using a callback is treated as a remote data source?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question.  I post an update which I believe is the correct answer.

Comment: use $.ui.autocomplete instead of $.ui.autosearch and now works fine